# Own build server configured with Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, build-server

We are using Visual Studio online (TFS) and now due to some activX licenses requirement we need to have our own build machine. We like to use Azure virtual machine for this. We need to install Build Server first but as we are using the Visual Studio Online we do not have the TFS installed on site. How can we proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your on-prem build server against a hosted visualstudio.com tfs account. This would be the same process for configuring your build server on an Azure VM.

See [bharry's blog on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/15/configuring-a-build-server-against-your-shiny-new-hosted-tfs-account.aspx)

Comment: In order to install Build Server we need to have TSF installation. But as we are using the hosted visualstudio.com we do not have any license for TFS. Do we need to have separate license to be able to install Build Server when we already have subscription for TFS visualstudio.com account.

Comment: I am not an expert on licenses but am pretty certain that you do not get any onprem Build/TFS licenses when you sign up for a visualstudio.com tfs account